# Connecting Firebase Storage and Compute Engine Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Now, I make an application that use google cloud platforms. First I use firebase and google cloud Compute Engine. 
In Android Studio , I make a folder in firebase Storage.
And, I want to use this folder in google Compute Engine. So I mounted this bucket and a directory in Compute Engine VM. However I can't see the folder that made by application. 
And, I try use 'gsutil' command , I can check this folder in my storage but I copied this folder to my directory , then my directory is deleted. What's the problem..... help me please...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky0X5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRuih.png)

Comment: as per the screenshot you sent you are trying to move the whole bucket root directory and this is not possible instead you should move all the object inside. For instance you should run $gsutil mv gs://youbucketname/* /home

Comment: I tried gustil  mv gs://bucket ~/anotherdirectory, then I can't check another directory because this directory didn't visible in my terminal... when I moved my bucket to my directory , this directory be disappeared....

Comment: Please try to run  gustil mv gs://bucket/*  ~/anotherdirectory